# Could be this:( $f$ is Lebesgue integral $\iff$ $f$ is Borel-summable ) works?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, summation-method

[Borel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation) is a summation method for divergent series, It is particularly useful for summing divergent asymptotic series, and in some sense gives the best possible sum for such series. and The main purpose of [Lebesgue integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration) is to provide an integral notion where limits of integrals hold under mild assumptions then both seeking for convergence or any function to be defined as well , Really i want to know if there is any connection between Borel summation and Lebesgue integral in the context when a function represented in a power series, i want to know for example :Could be this: $f$ is Lebesgue integral $\iff$ it is Borel-summable ?

**Note:** Here $f$ is smooth but non-analytic over $\mathbb{R+}$ and no explicit formula for the sequence $a_n$

Comment: In what sense is the function represented by a power series? If you have classical equality then on any open set, the function $f$ is analytic and there is no need for the machinery of lebesgue integration, nor for borel summability

Comment: in a formel power series when for example we don't have any explicit formula for the sequence a_n, When we can't estimate the rate growth of coefficients

Comment: If your function is only a formal power series then there isnt a way to use lebesgue integration theory though

Comment: and also f smooth and non-analytic

Comment: If $f$ is not analytic then the connection of the power series to the original function is a little tenuous.

Comment: If $f$ is merely a formal power series then there is an obvious series to obtain formally by integrating the power series term-by-term but this involves the integration of polynomials only and can be done symbolically even

Comment: no, see  for example the solution of this ODE :https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258525/how-do-i-solve-this-displaystyle-f-ef-1 , the solution is formal power series arround 0 but is not ovious function , since there is no explicit formula for a_n

Comment: Lebesgue integration theory is decidedly about integrating [equivalence classes of] *functions*. That ODE has no *function* solution...so there is no hope to use Lebesgue theory